# terminating because too few slides

Tags: jquery

I receive an error saying it is too few slides. May I know what is the problem?

```
function log() {
    if (window.console && window.console.log)
        window.console.log('[cycle] ' + Array.prototype.join.call(arguments,' '));
};
```

This is my html code and my jquery. I'm currently running under Google chrome and trying to use `onmouseover` effect but don't know if what I did now works or not. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Menu1").hover(
  function () { $("#td_1").show(); },
  function () { $("#td_1").hide(); }
);
    $("#Menu2").hover(
  function () { $("#td_2").show(); },
  function () { $("#td_2").hide(); }
);
    $("#Menu3").hover(
    function () { $("#td_3").show(); },
    function () { $("#td_3").hide(); }
  );
    $("#Menu4").hover(
  function () { $("#td_4").show(); },
  function () { $("#td_4").hide(); }
);
    $("#Menu5").hover(
  function () { $("#td_5").show(); },
  function () { $("#td_5").hide(); }
);
    $("#Menu6").hover(
  function () { $("#td_6").show(); },
  function () { $("#td_6").hide(); }
);
    $("#Menu7").hover(
  function () { $("#td_7").show(); },
  function () { $("#td_7").hide(); }
);
    $("#Menu8").hover(
  function () { $("#td_8").show(); },
  function () { $("#td_8").hide(); }
);
</script>

<tr>
          <td id="td_1" colspan="8" bgcolor="#CF0D0B" height="25"><div align="center" class="style101">
          <a href="open-live-account.aspx" class="style101">Open Live Account</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="/File/nzf4setup.exe" class="style101">Download</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="/deposit.aspx" class="style101">Deposit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="/withdraw.aspx" class="style101">Withdrawal</a>
              </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="td_2" colspan="8" bgcolor="#CF0D0B" height="25">
                                <div align="center" class="style101">
                                    <a href="open-live-account.aspx" class="style101">Open Live Account</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="deposit.html" class="style101">Deposit</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html"
                                        class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="withdraw.html" class="style101">Withdraw</a><a
                                            href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="trading-platform.html"
                                                class="style101">Trading Platform</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="market-hours.html" class="style101">Market Hours</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html"
                                        class="style101"></a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="trading-services.html" class="style101">Trading Services</a><a
                                        href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a></div>
            </td>
              </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="td_3" colspan="8" bgcolor="#CF0D0B" height="25"><div align="center" class="style101"><a href="education-center.html" class="style101">Education Center</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="risk-assessment.html" class="style101">Risk Assessment</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="risk-warning.html" class="style101">Risk Warning</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="money-management-responsible-trading.html" class="style101">Money Management &amp; Responsiblity Trading</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="td_4" colspan="8" bgcolor="#CF0D0B" height="25"><div align="center" class="style101"><a href="investment-news.html" class="style101">Investment news</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="economic-calendar.html" class="style101">Economic Calendar</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a></div></td>
              </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="td_5" colspan="8" bgcolor="#CF0D0B" height="25"><div align="center" class="style101"><a href="affiliate-program.html" class="style101">Affiliate Program</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="white-label.html" class="style101">White Label</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="td_6" colspan="8" bgcolor="#CF0D0B" height="25"><div align="center" class="style101"><a href="contact-us.aspx" class="style101">Contact Us</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="nzf-faq.html" class="style101">FAQ</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="site-map.html" class="style101">SiteMap</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a></div></td>
              </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="td_7" colspan="8" bgcolor="#CF0D0B" height="25"><div align="center" class="style101"><a href="about-us.html" class="style101">About Us</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="nzf-vision.html" class="style101">NZF Vision</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="careers.html" class="style101">Careers</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a></div></td>
              </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="td_8" colspan="8" bgcolor="#CF0D0B" height="25"><div align="center" class="style101"><a href="contact-us.aspx" class="style101">Contact Us</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="nzf-faq.html" class="style101">FAQ</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="site-map.html" class="style101">SiteMap</a><a href="nzf-seminar.html" class="style101"></a></div></td>
              </tr>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without even remotely knowing what your code looks like, I think it's a good guess that you are using jQuery cycle plugin and your HTML only has one slide making the plugin useless.
Cycle terminates because you only have one slide.

The code you included is not helpful at all. You could post your HTML and JS.